# Initializing a basic, one-shot iterator in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I am a new user of tensorflow, and am working with Datasets. As a primer, I have copied and used the following sample code from the [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets):

```
# the sample code doesn't tell me where the session comes from, so I wrote these few lines:
def my_initializer():
    return tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
my_initializer()

# back to sample code
dataset = tf.contrib.data.Dataset.range(100)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

for i in range(100):
  value = sess.run(next_element)  # <--- death stalks this line
  assert i == value
```

On the 1st call to `sess.run()` I see the following error:

> NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Function
>   _make_dataset_989f6fa6 is not defined.     [[Node: OneShotIterator = OneShotIteratorcontainer="",
>   dataset_factory=_make_dataset_989f6fa6[], output_shapes=[[]],
>   output_types=[DT_INT64], shared_name="",
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I have been bitten by a similar error every time I try to use an iterator. The objective here is simply to get a handle on the basic mechanics of feeding data to a graph. I do have a graph, but I have left it out of this post, because I don't think that is the problem at all.

Obviously, I am not understanding something very simple. Could someone help me out? 
Thank you.

Comment: Start simple: does [example in Creating an iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) (copy-pasted verbatim into an empty file, with only import statements added) work for you? What is your tensorflow version?

Comment: I found the problem: I was passing the session to eval(session=sess) earlier in the code.

Comment: Just to check: are you using TensorFlow 1.2 or 1.3? From the error message, I think you might be experiencing a bug that was fixed in 1.3.

Comment: >python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
>1.2.1

Comment: `# <--- death stalks this line` is an excellent comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error message "Function ... is not defined" when creating a `tf.data.Dataset` or `tf.data.Iterator`, upgrade to a newer version of TensorFlow. The error message is caused by a bug in TensorFlow 1.2, which was fixed in TensorFlow 1.3.

Comment: Even 1.4 is available now, hope OP fixed this :p